# WordPress Ajaxifying not working properly

Tags: functions, customization, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to Ajaxifying my form. Everything works fine, except the 2 things, 1) the `alert` triggered multiple times, 2) if I removed the `alert`, the ajax won't work instead after submitting the form it directs to `urldomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and it will displayed `0`.

UPDATE: I found some error
[image]

How to fix this?

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" id="modal-form-ajax" autocomplete="off">
        <input placeholder="Last Name*" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" required data-selectable="true">
        <input placeholder="First Name*" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" required data-selectable="true">
        <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" onblur="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" required data-selectable="true">
        <input placeholder="Mobile Number*" type="text" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="" size="11" minlength="11" maxlength="11" pattern ="^09\d{9}$" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your 11-digits Philippine mobile number')" onchange="try{ setCustomValidity('') } catch(e){}" required data-selectable="true">
        <button id="modal-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $("#modal-form-ajax").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var resumetest = $('input[name="form_title"]').val();
        var lastName = $('input[name="lastName"]').val();
        var firstName = $('input[name="firstName"]').val();
        var Email = $('input[name="Email"]').val();
        var contactNumber = $('input[name="contactNumber"]').val();
        alert (lastName);
        var ajaxUrl = { ajaxFormUrl: '//urldomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' }

          $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                lastName: lastName,
                firstName: firstName, 
                Email: Email,
                contactNumber: contactNumber,
                action: 'validate_form'
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Thank you for your application");
                console.log($('#modal-form-ajax').serialize());
                $("#modal-form-ajax").fadeOut('ease',function(){
                  $("#modal-form-ajax").html('<p>We\'ll get back to you shortly.</p>');
                  $("#modal-form-ajax").fadeIn('ease');
                });
              },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Form submission was unsuccessful");
              }
          });
     });
});
```

**PHP (functions.php)**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_validate_form', 'validate_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_form', 'validate_form');
function validate_form(){
    ob_clean();
    global $wpdb;
    $lastName               = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? filter_var($_POST['lastName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) : '';
    $firstName              = isset($_POST['firstName']) ? filter_var($_POST['firstName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) : '';
    $email                  = isset($_POST['Email']) ? filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) : '';
    $contactNumber          = isset($_POST['contactNumber']) ? filter_var($_POST['contactNumber'], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP) : '';

    echo do_shortcode("[cfdb-save-form-post]");

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you set the forms action attribute to # - no need to set an url here because you submit by using javascript.

Comment: Is your WordPress install in a subdirectory? Like example.com/wordpress, or something like that?

Comment: Add the code you use to register/enqueue/localize your JS please.

Comment: When `alert` changes the functionality of your code substantially, I've found it's often a timing issue where the alert is basically "pausing" your code, giving other code the chance to do something necessary for your code's completion. Look at your browser's developer tools, note any errors, and also look at the network tab, the ajax requests and their initiators to see where they got fired from.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, the WordPress is not installed in a subdirectory

Comment: @jdm2112, the js is inside the PHP file, since the form is a custom page template

Comment: @janh I''ve check the network tab, and I found out that there's a 400 bad request url: urldomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Look closely at that request and what makes it a bad request, especially at the parameters being sent.

Comment: @janh, the parameters sent correctly, I'm wondering, sometimes, the ajax is  working (the form submitted properly and displayed the `thank you` message), sometimes I got 400 bad request ajax.

Comment: Does the request include a nonce that's already been used? Is the 400 coming from WordPress, the Webserver or a potential reverse proxy in front of it?

Comment: I'm not yet include a `nonce`. Where should I put that? i've also noticed, that if the ajax form successfully submitted, there's a multiple data save even the user click only once the button

Comment: @janh, i tried to put `nonce` in my html form like this `<?php wp_nonce_field('validate_form_modal_nonce', 'name_of_nonce_field'); ?>`, and in my functions.php `if(!isset($_POST['name_of_nonce_field']) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['name_of_nonce_field'], 'validate_form_modal_nonce')){ exit('The form is not valid'); }` but still sometimes it redirects to `admin-ajax.php` this time I got a blank white page